# How to find out ALL windows schedule tasks which wake my pc up?

Tags: windows, batch-processing

I want to prevent my (win81) pc from being waked up (e.g. by night) by certain (but not all) tasks of the windows sheduler.

So I tried to find out, which windows scheduler tasks enabled 'Wake the computer to run this task' (under Scheduler/Task/Edit/Conditions). This can be checked manually for each task separatly, of course annoying for hundreds of tasks.

I'm wondering, if there is a possibilty to export a COMPLETE list of all tasks (XML/TXT/..), so that I can afterwards grep the tasks using 'true'.

Methods for 'mass export' are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408729/), but they apply to Win7 (my Win81 system does not contain any files in the described folders).

Any idea or other method to directly find these unwanted wakeup tasks?

Answer (score 2):

Solved: After some more googling around I've found the ms windows command shell tool ['schtask.exe'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357).

The following command line (in admin mode) generates the desired 'bulk export'

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /query /xml > c:/temp/all-tasks.xml
```

including the the searched tasks containing the pattern

```
<...>
<WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
<...>
```